# How to change path for a dynamically allocating files

Tags: python, pandas, dataframe

```
import pandas as pd


timestr = time.strftime("%Y%m%d-%H%M%S") + ' .csv'
df2.to_csv(timestr,sep='\t',encoding='utf-8')`
```

I want to change the directory of my .csv files. Like, now the .csv files are created in the same directory where my python script is present. I need to transfer all the .csv files to another directory. I actually am working with a dataset from which the dataframe object came and I have not included the dataframe code snippet since I felt that would not be required. I just need these .csv files to be moved to another directory.

Comment: `df2.to_csv(path + timestr, ...)` ? being `path` whatever path you want

Comment: By default files will be written to the process CWD (Current Working Directory); you must change this by specifying a unique path for each file or changing the CWD to whatever single instance you want.

Answer (score 0):

In case of linux this might do the trick

```
import os
#your code
#Your code
os.system('cp *.csv /path/to/your/directory')
```

Answer (score 0):

You can use [`os.path.join`](https://docs.python.org/3/library/os.path.html#os.path.join) to build cross-platform paths. For example:

```
import os, time
import pandas as pd

timestr = time.strftime("%Y%m%d-%H%M%S") + ' .csv'

outpath = os.path.join(r'C:\temp', timestr)

print(outpath)
# C:\temp\20180603-192044 .csv

df2.to_csv(outpath, sep='\t', encoding='utf-8')`
```

Answer (score 0):

You can use absolute path in `df2.to_csv(...)` call, e.g.

```
import os

timestr = time.strftime("%Y%m%d-%H%M%S") + ' .csv'
file_path = os.path.join('/my/csv/dir', timestr)
df2.to_csv(file_path, sep='\t', encoding='utf-8')
```

On a related note, [os](https://docs.python.org/3/library/os.html) is the module normally used to working with file system paths, e.g. [`os.getcwd()`](https://docs.python.org/3/library/os.html#os.getcwd) returns your current working directory and [`os.listdir(dir)`](https://docs.python.org/3/library/os.html#os.listdir) returns the list of files in `dir`.